# Формула Google Sheet для проверки соответствия номеров недель (5-недельный месяц)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

У меня есть таблица **Google Sheet** :
[image]

*SourceSheet Google Sheet (источник) доступен*: [SourceSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VW5d5Hx7BHu9SqXEKjHIti4a6758naDRBahhBDekhFI/edit?usp=drive_link)

---

Я пытаюсь создать формулу на другом листе , которая проверяет каждую строку (в исходном листе выше): **D10, D11, D12, D13** и т. д. Эти ячейки содержат текущую дату (день). Например 3 и 8 января.

- Проверяю, не пуста ли ячейка **D**. Если нет, продолжаю.
- Проверяю числа в этой ячейке (**D10, D11, D12**, ...)[дата] соответствует номеру проверенного столбца: **I, J, K, L, M**. Таким образом, **I** — 1-й столбец, **J** 2-й столбец, **K** 3-й, **L** 4-й, **М** 5-й. Эти столбцы представляют одну из 5 недель текущего месяца, если месяц разделить на 5 (а не на 4 недели).
- Если день (**D10, D11, D12** или другой) правильно соответствует номеру недели, проверяю следующую строку. Например, 3 ( **D10** ) находится на 1-й неделе, поэтому правильно указано в 1-м столбце **I10**.
- Если день (**D10, D11** или другой) не соответствует номеру недели (номер столбца). Например, **D10** равен 3, а второй столбец отмечен 1 в **J10** . Это ошибка, и формула возвращает 1 .
  Если какой-либо из столбцов ( **I:M** ) содержит какое-то другое значение вместо 1 , формула возвращает 1.
- Если какая-либо из строк (день) не соответствует номеру столбца (неделя), формула возвращает 1 и завершает работу. При отсутствии ошибок формула возвращает "".

---

Предполагается, что каждый месяц разделен на 5 недель. Не 4 недели. Например, январь разделен на 5 недель:
[image]

1 неделя — с 1 по 7. 2 неделя — с 8 по 14. 3 неделя — с 15 по 21. 4 неделя — с 22 по 28. 5 неделя — с 21 по 31.

---

Код:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VW5d5Hx7BHu9SqXEKjHIti4a6758naDRBahhBDekhFI/edit?usp=drive_link", "Sheet1!D10:D200"))), INT(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VW5d5Hx7BHu9SqXEKjHIti4a6758naDRBahhBDekhFI/edit?usp=drive_link", "Sheet1!D10:D200")/7)+1<>MATCH(1, IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VW5d5Hx7BHu9SqXEKjHIti4a6758naDRBahhBDekhFI/edit?usp=drive_link", "Sheet1!I10:M10"), 0)), 1, ""))<>"", 1, ""), "")
```

---

Не работает. Ожидаемый мной результат: если обнаружена одна ошибка (первая ошибка), то вся формула возвращает только 1 , и она печатается в моей ячейке как есть. Если во всех строках нет ошибок диапазоне, то формула возвращает только «» один раз и печатает в ячейке как есть. Можете помочь?

Comment: Формулы та не работают. Точнее работают, но это будет неоправданно сложное решение. Передумайте решение заново. Используйте принципы [ПРФ](https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/45242e42d50a39b0a957f695cff0dfa4)